# how should construct application architecture?

Tags: node.js, angular, hibernate, express, architecture

I am involved in new project, I would like to ask about big picture of project. I am planning to build new user interface for our website service. Currently, we have completed implementing all the necessary Rest API using Hibernate.

The technology we are using is Angular for front-end. I have  constructed small application using Angular2 which is implemented to be serviced on Tomcat server. The way I developed is very common way developers normally do. All the components are written in typescript which receive request, call RestAPI, retrieve JSON object from Rest API, and manipulate JSON and display resultant data using template. Those typescript files are transpiled into javascript using webpack, and those javascript files are deployed into tomcat.

But after research, now I get to know that nodejs is widely used instead of tomcat, in terms of performance, nodejs is much better than when using tomcat. Therefore, I am looking for some good examples to fit into our project architecture whose backend is built with RestAPI grounded on Hibernate. But, it is not found easily yet. The way I am thinking to call RestAPI from nodejs, I am not exactly sure, I tried to find some good practices but I could not find it well, really good examples. There are a lot of resources about MEAN stack but not for my case.

Could you give some advice about what I am trying to achieve? best practices, open source, and give some somehow detail explanation about the architecture what I have to build?

Comment: Is the node application the REST API, the static file server for the angular app, or both? If you have an API already and just want to use the angular application for the front end I’ve used the node application to serve the static files (html, js, &css), but I’ve seen more cost effective approaches that use S3 (or other storage solutions) to host the files.

Comment: I understand partly what you say, now, angular component calls RestAPI and receives JSON objects and display them on the browser, So, there is never need to connect to database in the nodejs, RestAPIs return every necessary JSON objects to any front end side application. So... if this is the way how my application works, serving the javascript files (transpiled from typescript) by putting them in the place where the static files are is the proper way I can build? Do you have  good examples where this is applied?

Answer (score 3):

It's a pretty broad question, but all you need is your rest web services backend should be running on node.js rather than in tomcat container. In node, people mostly use express (for both web app and api) or restify (primarily for web services api). And, there are numerous others. For ORM, you'll need to use something else other than Hibernate (which is really Java-specific). There are again tens of popular ORM frameworks in node.js. If you talk about MEAN, however, MongoDB is a NoSQL database, not a relational DB. Otherwise, architecture-wise, anything you can do in Java (tomcat, hibernate,...), you can do it in node.js.

Answer (score 0):

For the FrontEnd part- keep in mind that after compiling to JavaScript, all you need is to serve those static files from your server. 
A virtual directory will do.

Comment: Ah, I understand a little bit, do you have some good places where includes good examples the way you explained?

Comment: @AnnaLee I guess this link could help: http://acdhirr.blogspot.co.il/2013/11/tomcat-7-virtual-directories.html?m=1 After compilation of your Angular project, copy the **dist** folder to your virtual directory and point the configuration to this folder.

Comment: Yes, there was no problem to deploy into Tomcat, for this time, I would like nodejs to be container of application. That's what I want..

Comment: @AnnaLee It is highly recommended for most web apps to separate the FrontEnd project (angular) from the BackEnd (node.js). Of course it depends on your application needs. Do you plan to write your node.js app in TypeScript or pure JavaScript? I will attach some links accordingly...